# In UML class diagram, where to show DAO methods of a domain class

Tags: uml, dao, visio, class-diagram, domain-model

I am trying to build UML class diagram. I am a bit new to UML so pardon my ignorance.

I have a domain class `User` with these attributes:

- UserName ; data type is string ; identifier
- Password ; data type is string
- Active ; data type is bool
- Locked ; data type is bool
- PasswordExpiryDate ; data type is DateTime

So this is how I build it in UML:

[image]

Now I want to define these operations of this `User` class in UML class diagram:

1. Retrieve a User object by a supplied identifier from database.
2. Match password of the retrieved User object with a supplied
   password.
3. Check if the retrieved User is Active.
4. Check if the retrieved User is Locked.
5. Check if the retrieved User's password has expired.
6. Insert a User object in database.
7. Update a User object in database.
8. Delete a User object from database.

So this is how I build it in UML:

[image]

But I am very confused about method #1 "Retrieve a User object by a supplied identifier from database". 
All other methods are working on a single `User` object which means that single `User` object has already been retrieved from database or its a new object. 
But method #1 make sense to work on a collection of `User` objects which means all the user objects which already exist in the database.

Does it make sense? or is it a mismatch? If yes how can I fix it?

Thanks

---

### UPDATE

Thanks for mentioning the class-level operations in UML class diagram. I did not know about them.

So I have made the changes and this is the latest UML class diagram for `User` class:

[image]

Is it now correct?

Comment: I've refined my answer a bit. Notice that you should designate the attribute `UserName` as an ID attribute by appending `{id}` after `string`. Then also `DeleteUser` should just have a `userName` parameter. I'm explaining in my answer that also create/add and update would not have a `User` object as their parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that it's not only your method #1, but also your `AddUser` method to "work on a collection of User objects which means all the user objects which already exist in the database". In fact, all CRUD methods are distinct as they work on the corresponding database table population.

With a DAO approach, you would define your CRUD data access methods `retrieveUser`  and `deleteUser` in the form of class-level ("static") methods since they don't work with a context object (as remarked by Geert Bellekens), but rather take the object ID (in your case `UserName`) as their only parameter. The other two CRUD methods, `createUser`and `updateUser`, would also normally not work with a context object (in your case a `User` object), but rather have parameters for the data values entered via a user interface. In the case of `createUser` (your `AddUser`), a `User` object would only be created if the data values satisfy all constraints defined in the model class `User`. In the case of `updateUser`, an update would only be performed when the changed values do not violate any constraint.

Comment: I have updated the post with the class-level operations. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would model that one as a **static** or **Class** operation. You don't need a `User` instance for this type of operation.

The UML notation for a static method is to have it underlined.

---

*O.T. I would also combine `Add()` and `Update()` into one `Save()` operation. It's not up to the user of your object to keep track of the persistent state of your object. This would avoid issues such as adding an already existing object, or updating a non-existent object.*

Comment: I'm using a dedicated Singleton class to handle such a static access.

Comment: I have updated the post with the class-level operations. Is it ok now?